# Oval - Multiple ValidateWithMethod / complex custom validations with different messages?

Tags: java, validation, oval

I am trying to use @ValidateWithMethod to validate a property. I have two very different custom validations. I want to put them in separate methods so that I can have different messages. However, placing two separate @ValidateWithMethod attributes results in a 'duplicate annotation' compilation error.

What is the thing you're supposed to do in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the annotation syntax to be a bit tricky to figure out so I'm adding an example:

```
  @ValidateWithMethod.List(value={
    @ValidateWithMethod(methodName="foo", parameterType=String.class, ignoreIfNull=true, message="FooError"),
    @ValidateWithMethod(methodName="bar", parameterType=String.class, ignoreIfNull=true, message="BarError")
  })
  private String thing;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@ValidateWithMethod.List` annotation to declare multiple `@ValidateWithMethod` on the same element.